Issues with GCP Pub/Sub Publisher Template: Messages Show as errorChannel
how's it going? I'm trying to implement a template for a publisher on GCP Pub/Sub. I'm using a simple REST controller to send this message on port 8080.
@RestController
public class WebAppController {

    @Autowired
    PubSubOutboundGateway gateway;

    @PostMapping("/publishMessage")
    public String publishMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
        gateway.sendToPubSub(message);
        return "Message sent successfully";
    }
}

I have a topic created and a subscriber. The message is being sent with a 200 OK status, but when I pull from the subscriber, it appears as errorChannel, which seems to indicate that the message was not processed correctly and didn't enter any channel, not even replyChannel. Does anyone know a solution? Are there any good materials or videos on this? Just a sincere question.
this is my basic implementation of an outbound:

@Component
public class PubSubServiceActuator {

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public PubSubMessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, "testTopic");
    }
}

@MessagingGateway(name = "pubsubGateway", defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
public interface PubSubOutboundGateway {

    void sendToPubSub(String message);
}


spring.application.name=madlib-gcp-template
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=<>
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:<>
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.executor-threads=4
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-ack-extension-period=6000

#spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-pull-request-queue-size=1000
#spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-pull-request-queue-timeout=3000
#spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.ack-deadline=30s

using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub e spring-integration-core. version 5.5.0
enter image description here
I've tried changing my properties by setting subscriber.executor-threads, max-ack-extension-period, and increasing the timeout and I couldn't create an error handler to manage this.

Maybe you should take a look at this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub
